# getting TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when attempting to access localhost:8080 with Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, redirect, spring-security, configuration, java-17

Using last version of spring.
I've followed [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) guide step by step, checked it again and again, but I'm seeing this when I try accessing localhost:8080:

[image]

Here's my WebConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout(LogoutConfigurer::permitAll);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

Together with the 3 html files:
[image]

I've searched for this throughout the entire web and found no solution. Is there anything the guide or I am missing?
There's no controller or mapping whatsoever inside the code. Just the webconfig and static files.

P.s. I see no Spring Security password being generated when starting up the app:
[image]

is this a normal thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/login` `HTTP.GET` mapping is not being resolved by any **MVCController**.

Add a folder named controller and create a `MVCController.java` file inside it with the following content:

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MVCController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MVCController.class);

    @GetMapping(value = "/login")
    public String login() {
        LOG.info("/login");

        LOG.info("Return login");

        //return login.html located in /resources/templates
        return "login";
    }
}
```

After adding this, when you go the `http://localhost:8080`, the login page should be presented.

Comment: yess this solved it! It was my bad having omitted the creation of a View Controller which the guide actually suggested to create but in a MVC manner and not as a @ Controller. In fact, I had created the Controller in the first place but with @ RestController, which was just responding with the string "login", and that's why I decided to delete it, without thinking of @ Controller instead. My bad. Thank you!